# Slicing up to 15 items after a certain item in a python list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying loop through a list in python and compare each element in the list to the next 15 elements in the list. I want something like the following code, but I don't know how to say it in python. Also, I want to do it without importing anything extra.

```
for i in S:
    for j in S[i: '''up 15 elements after i or however much is left if less than 15''']
        #do some comparisons
```

So basically, for the inside loop, I only want to iterate from item i to item i+15 (or whatever is left), without importing iterator or such.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an index:

```
for index, i in enumerate(S):
    for j in S[index+1:index+16]
        #do some comparisons
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks @anthon, exactly this. You're quick! This is only my second python program, I didn't know about enumerate(). I'm not sure I understand why j doesn't go past the bounds of S, but it works great.

Comment: Python slicing automatically adjust the index to the upper limit of what is available so you **don't** have to do a cumbersome `S[index+1:max(index+16,len(S)]`

Answer (score 4):

You can just do `S[i:i+15]` and it will only slice until the end of the list, if there are less than 15 elements after index `i`

Edit:

If `i` is not the index, and you need the index use `enumerate()` as in Anthon's answer.

Comment: i is not an index in S, it is an element of S